# Pruning symmetrical solutions in prolog

Tags: prolog

Suppose we want to write the predicate *schedule/6* in **native** prolog which, given a list of jobs, creates a schedule for N workers, where each worker can work for H hours total max.

A job is represented as such:

```
job(Name, time(StartTime, EndTime))
```

The prolog source could look like this: (suppose that *overlapping/3* checks if a job overlaps with a person's currently assigned jobs)

```
schedule(_, _, _, [], Schedule, Schedule).
schedule(N, CurrentPerson, H, Jobs,  CurrentSchedule, Schedule):-
    CurrentPerson =< N,
    scheduleP(CurrentPerson, H, Jobs, RemainingJobs, 0, CurrentSchedule, UpdatedSchedule),
    NewPerson is CurrentPerson + 1,
    schedule(N, NewPerson, H, RemainingJobs, UpdatedSchedule, Schedule).    


scheduleP(CurrentPerson, H, [job(A, time(Y,Z)) | T1], RemainingJobs, Time, CurrentSchedule, Schedule):-
    NewTime is Time + (Z - Y),
    NewTime =< H,
    \+ overlapping(CurrentPerson, time(Y,Z), CurrentSchedule),
    scheduleP(CurrentPerson, H, T1, RemainingJobs, NewTime, [CurrentPerson - A | CurrentSchedule], Schedule).

scheduleP(CurrentPerson, H, [job(A, time(Y,Z)) | T1], [job(A, time(Y,Z)) | T2], Time, CurrentSchedule, Schedule):-
    NewTime is Time + (Z - Y),
    NewTime =< H,
    overlapping(CurP, act(Y,Z), CurASA),
    scheduleP(CurrentPerson, H, T1, T2, Time, CurrentSchedule, Schedule).

scheduleP(_, _, RemainingJobs, RemainingJobs, _, Schedule, Schedule).
```

Basically, the code above is supposed to return a list of elements in the format of

```
Person - JobName
```

indicating which person took which job.
By asking for more solutions, the predicate generates the next possible permutation.

The thing is, how can one prevent it from displaying symmetrical solutions?
For example, if the input job list is

```
[ job(a1, time(0,3)), job(a2, time(4,6)), job(a3, time(1,2)) ]
```

then the some of the outputs of the following call would be:

```
schedule(2,1, 10, [ job(a1, time(0,3)), job(a2, time(4,6)), job(a3, time(1,2)) ], Schedule).

Schedule = [1 - a1, 1 - a2, 2 - a3]

;

Schedule = [2 - a1, 2 - a2, 1 - a3]
```

But those two solutions are considered to be symmetrical.
Is it possible to do this in native prolog without using setof/3 ? (for large problems it would be troublesome).

Comment: There is nothing specific to [tag:iso-prolog] in your question.

Comment: `[1 - a1, 1 - a2, 2 - a3]` and `[2 - a1, 2 - a2, 1 - a3]` are considered symmetrical? It's implicitly obvious, and `setof/3` wouldn't consider them the same either. Maybe you need a rule that succeeds if two arguments are symmetrical? Then you can use that to build your solution list and avoid symmetrical solutions.

Comment: @lurker That is what I did previous to writing this. I made it so that my argument returned a sorted list of lists, representing the solution (each inner list represented the assignments of a person), and then *setof/3* would automatically snip them off after it found all the solutions. That is highly problematic when it comes to large problems. What I am asking for is a way to prune said solutions inside the recursive predicate, as to avoid having to actually find every solution.

Comment: Generally, you want to prune as soon in the selection process as possible. I'm not sure what your symmetry criterion is, so where that specifically fits in your problem depends upon that.